# Please advice how to get rid of unmet dependency issue

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, scanner

I faced the problem of installing the software. It was stated something about unmet depedencies with the bitdefender-scanner:i386 package (its antivirus that I was trying to install the day before but something went wrong and it wasn't installed at all)
And now I'm getting errors while instalation of other software.

Here is what I get in the terminal when im trying to delete this damn package:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for beast: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
bitdefender-scanner:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 141 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 251963 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bitdefender-scanner (7.7.1-1809) ...
find: `/opt/BitDefender-scanner/share/locale': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package bitdefender-scanner (--remove):
subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
bitdefender-scanner
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried all from this post: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) but it didn't help. I still cannot install software due to this problem.
My OS: 14.04lts,x64

Please assist and advise how to prevent it in future. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `post-removal` script

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/bitdefender-scanner.postrm
```

and delete the line

```
set -e
```

But be in mind, that's only a good idea, if you have to force the removal of a package.

> The package management system looks at the exit status from these scripts. It is important that they exit with a non-zero status if there is an error, so that the package management system can stop its processing. For shell scripts this means that you almost alwaysneed to use set -e (this is usually true when writing shell scripts, in fact). It is also important, of course, that they exit with a zero status if everything went well.

Finally, remove the package again

```
sudo apt-get purge bitdefender-scanner
sudo apt-get autoremove bitdefender-scanner
```